# What is the maximum safe line length in css files?

Tags: css, cross-browser

YUI Compressor and other minifiers tend to remove unnecessary whitespaces, causing long lines. Safari 5 seems to fail rendering some rules from the css files when the file has [more than 5000 characters per line (blog post about my experiences)](http://www.villescorner.com/2013/04/yui-compressor-safari-5.html).

UglifyJS has a [`--max-line-len` (default 32K characters)](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) and the author says at the page

> *I’ve seen both FF and Chrome croak when all the code was on a single
>   line of around 670K*

**What is the maximum safe line length in css files?** I would like to support most of the still active browsers, while still removing unnecessary whitespaces. Any references to specifications would be useful.

Comment: I know this is not the question you asked but have you considered SASS/LESS? Additionally to hit the limit is a heck load of code is this well optimized without YUI? for example if you have `.bank{background:#000000;}` and `.ted{background:#000000;}` this could be made into `.bank,.ted{background:#000;}`. As YUI compressor only removes white space and doesn't make the code optimized. Though sounds like a load of code to optimise :P

Answer (score 1):

To quote the [Closure Compiler FAQ](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/faq#linefeeds):

> The Closure Compiler intentionally adds line breaks every 500
>   characters or so. Firewalls and proxies sometimes corrupt or ignore
>   large JavaScript files with very long lines. Adding line breaks every
>   500 characters prevents this problem. Removing the line breaks has no
>   effect on a script's semantics. The impact on code size is small, and
>   the Compiler optimizes line break placement so that the code size
>   penalty is even smaller when files are gzipped.

jQuery (1.7.2) has a 32k single line limit. Since jQuery is a widely used library, I would use the 32k character limit as a guideline.

Comment: 500 characters is also a good limit for text editors (on the rare occasions you need to open a minified file).

Comment: but he asked about CSS not JS